# How to check if a string is in an array

Tags: c#

I am trying to check whether a string is in an array and if continues even though the fileInfo.Name.Contains a string that is in files.Any:

```
\\FILES LIKE DATABASE.MDB IS IN C:PROJECTS\HOLON\DATABASE.MDB
                        **if (files.Any((fileInfo.Name.Contains)))** 
\\DO SOMETHING
                        Console.WriteLine(
                         fileInfo.Name, fileInfo.Length,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (Array.Exists(files, element => element.Contains(fileInfo.Name)))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you alread have the filenames collected in an array, then you should either do it this way:

```
if (files.Any() && files.Contains(fileInfo.Name))
{
   // Do something
}
```

If you just want to check if a file exists then you can use File.Exists:

```
if(System.IO.File.Exists(fileInfo.Name))
{
    // Do Something
}
```

Comment: @PrashantPimpale no, you can use files.Any() also to check if there is any data in the array, because this method returns bool.

Comment: Yup got it! I thought it was related to fileName exists or file exists related!

Answer (score 0):

So you have a collection of full file paths? And you want to check if one or more of those list entries match with a specific file name?

Perhaps this would work for you:

```
string fileToSearch = "DATABASE.MDB";
bool found = files.Any(fileName => new FileInfo(fileName).Name.ToUpper() == fileToSearch.ToUpper());
```

Edit:

An alternative to constructing new FileInfo objects would be to use System.IO.Path:

```
bool found = files.Any(fileName => Path.GetFileName(fileName).ToUpper() == fileToSearch.ToUpper());
```

Edit 2:

On the other hand, if you want to search for a specific file name, and you want to use the result, you could do something like this:

```
var fileToSearch = "DATABASE.MDB";

var fileInfo =
    (from f in files
     let fi = new FileInfo(f)
     where fi.Name.ToUpper() == fileToSearch.ToUpper()
     select fi).FirstOrDefault();

if (fileInfo != null)
{
    if (fileInfo.Exists)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{fileInfo.Name} ({fileInfo.Length} bytes).");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{fileInfo.Name} (does not exist).");
    }
}
```

I used a LINQ query here for readability. You could use the extension methods (`files.Select(f => new FileInfo(f)).Where(fi => fi.Name.ToUpper() == fileToSearch.ToUpper()).FirstOrDefault()`) as well, but that's up to you.